# To free memory allocated for an array of struct in c

Tags: c

I have a question about freeing the memory that I have allocated for an array of struct in c.

I have search the questions that was posted and nothing did clarify my problem.

First of all, I have created couple of structure beforehand; the variables inside the struct are all of a fixed size, such as `char str[250]` or `int`.

I was created couple of struct pointer and use malloc to turn it as an array of struct.

But when I was trying to free these arrays of struct, it won't free for some reason.

When I check for the memory leak through valgrind, it told me that I could not free the memory and I would definitely lost the memory on these arrays of struct.

The following is piece of code that is similar to my structure; the method of my malloc on my array of struct; and the method of my free memory.

```
struct word{
  char word[250];
  int occurrence; };

struct same_word{
  char word[250];};

int main(int argc, char** agrv){
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
         perror("File does not open.");
         exit(0);
    }

    int total_number_of_word = /*number of word I have in my txt file*/
    int total_number_of_same_word = /*number of same word I have in my txt file*/
    /* Assuming I knew these two numbers in advance*/

    struct word* essay = malloc(total_number_of_word * sizeof(struct word));
    struct same_word* unique_word = malloc(total_number_of_same_word * sizeof(struct same_word));

    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    while(index < total_number_of_word){
          fscanf(fp,"%s",essay[index].word);
          essay[index].occurrence = 1;
          ret = strcmp(essay[index].word,"Hello");
          if( ret == 0)
          {
               strcpy(unique_word[index2].word,essay[index].word);
               index2++;
          }
          index++;
    }
    free(essay);
    free(unique_word);
    fclose(fp);
```

}

Thanks in advance.

P.S
Thanks for all of you who have pointed out the mistakes I have in my question.

Comment: Is this a minimal, complete, verifiable example? (I think not, since it's an infinite loop)

Comment: Seconding immibis; if you were to add just `i++` inside the while loop, this definitely looks as though it should work. Please try to make a minimal example that you can compile and run and see the same behavior with.

Comment: you shoud test if the pointer to the memory allocated isn't equal to NULL. Also, if you change the value of the pointer in the loop, e.g, essay++, you won't be able to free.

Comment: @qleguennec I don't understand what you mean by "change the clue of the pointer in the loop" could you please explain a bit more for me?

Comment: `strcpy(essay[index],"hello");` should obviously be `strcpy(essay[index].word,"hello");`

Comment: @immibis O I was fast typing the question therefore I haven't notice that I didn't type in index++ for the while loop, thanks for the point out . I have already change it, it is suppose to be a finite loop that will run for the size of my array of struct.

Comment: Please be ruthlessly consistent in your layout of your code.  Please do not use the 'Pico style' [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) layout in C; use either Allman (which I use) or 1TBS.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks for the point out, I should have more careful on proofreading my example.

Comment: What you're using is not a 'static array of struct'.  That would be something like `static struct word[20];`.  You have a dynamically allocated array of structures.

Comment: As written, you have one `malloc()` and one `free()`, and the value you free is the value returned by `malloc()`. That's all good. When you compile and run this code, (a) does the compiler give it a clean bill of health, and (b) does it reproduce the problem when run under `valgrind`. If (a) is an issue, fix the code until it is squeaky clean. If (b) is an issue, what you've given us to analyze isn't sufficiently like your real problem to be useful. Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]). You're clearly aware of the concept, but if the code doesn't reproduce the problem, it's not OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the clarify on static array of struct

Comment: I see I botched the `static struct word arrayname[20];` notation in my previous comment about 'static array of structures' — sorry.  However, the general comment remains valid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for telling me that my code in the question is not valid for asking the problem, I have edit it and now it is exactly what I have done in my original program with less details.

Answer (score 0):

With minimal changes to the code:

1. `agrv` changed to `argv`.
2. Test `argc` before using `argv[1]`, exiting and reporting failure.
3. Test result from `scanf()` and exiting when it is not `1`.
4. Setting numbers of words to 1000 each.
5. Asserting that the memory allocations succeeded (so also using `#include <assert.h>`).
6. Closing the file.
7. Adding return 0 at the end.

the code compiled and ran cleanly under `valgrind` on Mac OS X 10.11.4 El Capitan.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word
{
    char word[250];
    int occurrence;
};

struct same_word
{
    char word[250];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("File does not open.");
        return 1;
    }

    int total_number_of_word = 1000;
    int total_number_of_same_word = 1000;

    struct word *essay = malloc(total_number_of_word * sizeof(struct word));
    struct same_word *unique_word = malloc(total_number_of_same_word * sizeof(struct same_word));
    assert(essay != 0);
    assert(unique_word != 0);

    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    while (index < total_number_of_word)
    {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%s", essay[index].word) != 1)
            break;
        essay[index].occurrence = 1;
        ret = strcmp(essay[index].word, "Hello");
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            strcpy(unique_word[index2].word, essay[index].word);
            index2++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(essay);
    free(unique_word);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run (program name `wd`; source code `wd.c`):

```
$ make wd && valgrind wd wd.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror wd.c -o wd 
==24802== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24802== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24802== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24802== Command: wd wd.c
==24802== 
==24802== 
==24802== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24802==     in use at exit: 22,233 bytes in 186 blocks
==24802==   total heap usage: 273 allocs, 87 frees, 538,561 bytes allocated
==24802== 
==24802== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24802==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24802==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24802==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24802==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24802==         suppressed: 22,233 bytes in 186 blocks
==24802== 
==24802== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24802== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 18 from 18)
$
```

The large number of memory 'in use at exit' and 'suppressed' is normal on Mac OS X.

If you are running into problems, then  one plausible source of trouble is that you did not allocate enough space in the two arrays.  You should really check that the values of `index` and `index2` are within bounds.  You probably could afford to reduce the length of a word — 250 is rather long; I might use 64 instead.  You should then use `%63s` in the `scanf()` format string to prevent overflows (or use `%249s` with the current structures).  There are only 136 words in the source code, and 1241 characters.  The longest 'words' are 32 characters each (`malloc(total_number_of_same_word` is one of them; the other is `strcpy(unique_word[index2].word,`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I never know that I could use %249s to prevent the overflow of my variable. 
I have managed to free some of my array of struct by freeing it right after I don't need it instead of freeing it at the end of the program.
But I still have some arrays of struct that are still not able to free when I try to free it after I done using them.
At the same time, I found out that valgrind has reported to me that my FILE* pointer is still reachable even I have use fclose() to close the txt file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have caught the problem in the program. I highly appreciate the help from you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your help, after hours of inspection towards couple thousands lines of code, I have finally caught where was the problem in the program.

Since I am doing a group work with 4 other people. Therefore the code is touching by 4 different hands, one of our group mate created an if statement that will end the program right the way by return 0.

But she forgot to release all the heap memory that we have been creating by malloc() neither nor commenting any of her code. So I didn't caught this silly problem right the way.

I am going to post the WRONG code that we have before and the CORRECT code we have right now in here for someone who may get the same silly question as we do.

This is the WRONG Version of our code

```
    struct word{
      char word[250];
      int occurrence; };

    struct same_word{
      char word[250];};

    int main(int argc, char** agrv){
        FILE* fp;
        fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");//argv[1] is the location where we put the txt file name
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
             perror("File does not open.");
             exit(0);
        }

        int total_number_of_word = /*number of word I have in my txt file*/
        int total_number_of_same_word = /*number of same word I have in my txt file*/
        /* Assuming I knew these two numbers in advance*/

        struct word* essay = malloc(total_number_of_word * sizeof(struct word));
        struct same_word* unique_word = malloc(total_number_of_same_word * sizeof(struct same_word));

        int index = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        int ret = 0;
        while(index < total_number_of_word){
              fscanf(fp,"%s",essay[index].word);
              essay[index].occurrence = 1;
              ret = strcmp(essay[index].word,"Hello");
              if( ret == 0)
              {
                   strcpy(unique_word[index2].word,essay[index].word);
                   index2++;
              }
              index++;
        }
        //...
        if( /*a event is true*/)
        {
              /*she has forgot to free memory before the return 0 
                therefore we have been continuously leaking memory*/
              return 0;
        }
        //...
        free(essay);
        free(unique_word);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
```

The following is the CORRECT Version of out code

```
struct word{
  char word[250];
  int occurrence;
};

struct same_word{
  char word[250];
};

int main(int argc, char** agrv){
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");//argv[1] is the location where we put the txt file name
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
         perror("File does not open.");
         exit(0);
    }

    int total_number_of_word = /*number of word I have in my txt file*/
    int total_number_of_same_word = /*number of same word I have in my txt file*/
    /* Assuming I knew these two numbers in advance*/

    struct word* essay = malloc(total_number_of_word * sizeof(struct word));
    struct same_word* unique_word = malloc(total_number_of_same_word * sizeof(struct same_word));

    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    while(index < total_number_of_word){
          fscanf(fp,"%s",essay[index].word);
          essay[index].occurrence = 1;
          ret = strcmp(essay[index].word,"Hello");
          if( ret == 0)
          {
               strcpy(unique_word[index2].word,essay[index].word);
               index2++;
          }
          index++;
    }
    //...
    if(/* a event is true*/)
    {
          free(essay);
          free(unique_word);
          fclose(fp);
          /* After freeing memory in here, we no longer have any memory leak*/
          return 0;
    }
    //...
    free(essay);
    free(unique_word);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Again, Thanks for the help from all of you. Since I do not ask question in this platform often, I do not know the perfect way to ask my question. I am sorry for not creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example at the first time.

But thanks for pointing it out, I will try to do it better next time I ask a question. I highly appreciate all the explanation and the advise.